# Is there a "Responsive Design + Server Side Components" (RESS) framework for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, responsive-design

I need to create a webapp that adapts to the metaphor of whatever platform is using it and to that  end would like to use "Responsive Web Design" specifically I would like to use RESS "Responsive Design + Server Side Components" where some of the UI tranformation is done server-side as bring the traffic to the device to a minimum.

I know from googling around there is a ready-made framework in the Drupal world, but I would like the app to be pure C# .NET, does anyone have a solution for this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 4 makes it pretty easy to implement a responsive design depending on the client. A few options available:

- adaptive rendering using viewport meta tag and CSS3 media queries - same content gets served, but UI adapts itself to the browser/device being displayed on
- display modes - out of the box, if a request originates from a mobile device, MVC will prefer a view with the name convention: e.g. MyView.mobile.cshtml instead of MyView.cshtml, in which you can render a completely different UI for mobile devices. You can create your own display mode providers to further control the outpu based on information that comes in in the Http Request. e.g. for ipads, show views with convention: MyView.ipad.cshtml

Display modes allows you to really control how much goes over the wire to the client as you can render completely different output. But usually, a mix of the 2 helps you create a responsive/adaptive web application.

Links:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/06/asp-net-mvc-4-overview-part-2-default-template-changes-and-adaptive-rendering.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn296507.aspx

Is this the kind of thing you are after?